# android: layout_marginBottom doesn't seem to work properly in 2.2 (Froyo)

Tags: android, layout

I have this ImageView block inside a Relative layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="81dip"
    android:src="@drawable/swipehelp"
    />
```

This draws the image right where it would be expected in both normal and high density resolution screens on Android 1.6 however on 2.2 it seems to ignore the layout_marginBottom and always draw the image aligned all the way at the bottom. Has anyone seen this before, and if so do you know a fix?

### Edit 1:

It sits inside a RelativeLayout declared thusly:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/excusescreen"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/woodbg">
```

### Edit 2:

Here's the full layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/excusescreen"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/woodbg">
   <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imlateTopBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dip"
    android:background="@drawable/topandbottombars"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
    >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/excHomeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
            android:src="@drawable/catexcusehomebtn"
            >
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/excBackToCatsBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
            android:src="@drawable/backtocats"
            >
    </ImageView>
     </LinearLayout>
     <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/excuses"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
     >
     </ViewFlipper>
     <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imlateTopBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dip"
    android:background="@drawable/topandbottombars"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emailItBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
        android:src="@drawable/emailit"
        >
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numExcusesText"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
        android:textColor="#66ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="1/13"
        >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shareItBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
        android:src="@drawable/shareit"
        >
    </ImageView>
     </LinearLayout>
     <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="81dip"
    android:src="@drawable/swipehelp"
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

### Edit 3

[image]

Comment: What container is the ImageView in?

Comment: See my edit for the container.

Comment: It draws just about right for me. Whats the size of the the drawable woodbg?

Comment: It's 320x455. It's weird. I'm just not sure why it would lay things out properly in 1.6 but not 2.2

Comment: see edit 2 for full layout code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of searching I found a link to this Issue that actually dates back to 09 but the comments from 2010 show lots of problems with alignParentBottom in 2.2.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1394

So, I did a workaround by putting the whole thing in a FrameLayout and made the ImageView a child of that outside my RelativeLayout and placed with the layout_gravity. That did the trick and made it work in all versions. Here's the final code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/excusescreen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/woodbg"
    android:clipChildren="true">
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imlateTopBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dip"
    android:background="@drawable/topandbottombars"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
    >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/excHomeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
            android:src="@drawable/catexcusehomebtn"
            >
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/excBackToCatsBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
            android:src="@drawable/backtocats"
            >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/excuses"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
>
</ViewFlipper>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imlateTopBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dip"
    android:background="@drawable/topandbottombars"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emailItBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
        android:src="@drawable/emailit"
        >
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numExcusesText"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
        android:textColor="#66ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="1/13"
        >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shareItBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
        android:src="@drawable/shareit"
        >
    </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
    android:src="@drawable/swipehelp"
    />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I have the problem in a FrameLayout, using layout_gravity = bottom is the thing that seems to make it work, however the whole view (if it is fill_parent or the parent is wrap_content) is cropped/moved to the top instead of being resized :(, as if the size was calculated before the margins.

Answer (score 14):

In the `FrameLayout` add a `View` with the following:

```
android:id="@+id/gap"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Now, in order to fix the `layout_marginBottom`, use the above:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/gap"
```

Answer (score 1):

It was the same for Android 1.6 for me until I changed the `layout_height` to `fill_parent` on the outermost 'RelativeLayout`

Apparently it can't get the bounds correct when settings it to `wrap_content`. If there is no special reason for having the `RelativeLayout`s width and height to wrap to it's content I'd say specify it like that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/excusescreen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/woodbg"
    android:clipChildren="true">
    <!-- all the other stuff -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Tried it, and still no luck though :-(

Comment: Could you post up the woodbg drawable?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add an additional View you can use a [InsetDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Inset) with `android:insetBottom` set.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem and used a LinearLayout positioned with ParentBottom, giving that a padding, and putting the image/button/view inside it. Using a margin on the target instead of a padding on the LinearLayout works as well btw.